# Need to delete cells which contains "0" and retaining other cells in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

My data frame contains "0" values in the cell. I need to call out the values(letters/non-zero`s) and their corresponding ticket number. Data frame(m) looks like: (Please note: column name is similar to its values)

```
       a1   b1  c1  d1  e1  f1  g1  h1  i1  j1  k1  l1
TKT1   a1   b1  0   d1  0   0   0   h1  0   0   k1  0
TKT2   0    b1  0   0   e1  0   g1  h1  0   j1  k1  0
TKT3   a1   0   0   d1  e1  0   g1  h1  i1  0   k1  l1
```

**Code for generating dataset:**

```
#sample data
m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 12*3, replace=T), ncol=12)
colnames(m) <- c("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1", "i1", "j1", "k1", "l1")
rownames(m) <- c("TKT1","TKT2","TKT3")

#replacement
ones <- which(m==1, arr.ind=T)
m[ones]<-colnames(m)[ones[,2]]
m <- as.data.frame(m)
```

My desired output format is:

```
Tickets Values
  TKT1  a1
  TKT1  b1
  TKT1  d1
  TKT1  h1
  TKT1  k1
  TKT2  b1
  TKT2  e1
  TKT2  g1
  TKT2  h1
  TKT2  j1
  TKT2  k1
  TKT3  a1
  TKT3  d1
  TKT3  e1
  TKT3  g1
  TKT3  h1
  TKT3  i1
  TKT3  k1
  TKT3  l1
```

One approach which came to my mind is to delete cells in my data frame if they contain 0 and then shift all the data leftwards. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: using `dplyr`, first make row.names into column, melt your data (`reshape2`), filter out the zeros, sort according to tickets.. `df %>% add_rownames('Tickets') %>% melt(id.var="Tickets") %>% filter(value!=0) %>% select(-variable)`

Comment: Thanks agenis for your direction. I am still trying to understand your code. Using your code, in output, 'Tickets' column takes the row index values(1,2,3) not TKT1, TKT2,TKT3. Any suggestion how to bring ticket number values instead of row index? (As shown above in desired output format). Also it gives me warning "attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped".

Comment: well, if you post the `dput()` of your first data.frame, I'll be able to see the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there is no set.seed for random generation of your data.frame, the result will be slightly different:

```
library(dplyr); library(reshape2)
m %>% add_rownames('Tickets') %>% melt(id.var="Tickets") %>% filter(value!=0) %>% select(-variable) %>% arrange(Tickets)
```

This gives the expected result.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done in base `r` with one line:

```
setNames(expand.grid(dimnames(m))[m != "0",], c("Tickets", "Values"))
```

`expand.grid` gives all the combinations of row and column names, and then `m != "0"` selects the entries that are not zero.  `setNames` gives names the columns.

Comment: Thanks Barker, your code is also working for me. I didn`t knew about 'expand.grid'. Its a new learning for me.

Comment: Creating a larger "data.frame" only to be subsetted immediately (especially if the number of "!= 0" is small) could be avoided by finding the non-zeros first -- `w = which(m != "0", TRUE); data.frame(tickets = rownames(m)[w[, "row"]], values = colnames(m)[w[, "col"]])
`

Comment: @alexis_laz that is a nice solution too.  You should submit it as an answer and I would definitely up vote.

Answer (score 0):

`library(tidyverse)` single pipe solution:

```
dfLong <- 
    m %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Tickets") %>% # newly refactored dplyr function
    gather(Keys, Values, a1:l1) %>% # tidyr:: gather all columns into key, value pairs
    filter(Values == Keys) %>% # select the matched cells
    select(-Keys) %>% # remove superfluous column
    arrange(Tickets, Values) # order correctly for desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a one liner using `library(data.table)`:

```
melt(setDT(m, keep.rownames = "Tickets"), id.vars = "Tickets")[, variable := NULL][value != "0"]
```

The use of `melt` is similar to the answer of @agenis.